# Where was green squadron at the Battle of Yavin and the Battle of Scarif?

Tags: star-wars, the-rebel-alliance

During the major space battles of the Star Wars original trilogy (and in Rogue One), the call signs of all flights are called out. I have noticed, though, that green squadron is not mentioned in either the Battle of Scarif or the Battle of Yavin, even though according to Star Wars Rebels they have existed for (at least) 2 years.

So where is green squadron? Are they the other X-wings in this shot?

[image]

Comment: Star Wars Rebels is not a completed show, they may have suffered some fate by the end, or in the ~4 years between the show and Rouge One. OR simply not been at those battles, instead off doing something else.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Although it's not clear why they weren't identified in the films, supplementary material indicates that Green Squadron in fact *was* present at both the Battle of Scarif and the Battle of Yavin.

### *Rogue One*

The novelization specifically mentions Green Squadron departing Yavin (emphasis mine):

> Less than ten minutes later, sirens were announcing the departure of Red, Blue, **Green**, and Gold Squadrons along with the U-wing transports. Raddus had already contacted all capital ships within range of Yavin or Scarif.
>
> <sup>*Rogue One: A Star Wars Story Official Novelization* Chapter 17</sup>

And the film's visual guide names three members of Green Squadron present at the battle:

1. Broan Danurs, Green Ten:

   [image]
2. Attico Wred, Green Four:

   [image]
3. Wion Dellems, Green Twelve:

   [image]

### *A New Hope*

The original 1976 novelization, ghostwritten by Alan Dean Foster, again calls out Green Squadron (emphasis mine):

> "Remember," the General went on, "you must achieve a direct hit. Yellow squadron will cover for Red on the first run. **Green** will cover Blue on the second. Any questions?"
>
> <sup>*Star Wars* Chapter 11</sup>

This is reportedly also mentioned in the recently-released short story compilation *From a Certain Point of View*, but I haven't read that one yet and so can't directly confirm.

Comment: I think it would be more useful to edit that comment into the other answer itself.