# Which capital ships came to the Battle of Scarif?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one, battle-of-scarif

While re-reading my [first post](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/174318/where-was-green-squadron-at-the-battle-of-yavin-and-the-battle-of-scarif) on this stackexchange, I noticed this mentioned in a quote from the accepted answer:

> Less than ten minutes later, sirens were announcing the departure of Red, Blue, **Green**, and Gold Squadrons along with the U-wing transports. **Raddus had already contacted all capital ships within range of Yavin or Scarif.**
>
> <sup>*Rogue One: A Star Wars Story Official Novelization* Chapter 17</sup>

The bold section suggests there were a number of capital ships other than the Profundity that took part in the battle. **What capital ships from the rebel alliance took part in the Battle of Scarif?**

Comment: There's a (fairly) comprehensive list here; https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Battle_of_Scarif

Comment: @Valorum You suggesting that Wookieepedia may have missed something?

Comment: Correcting Wookieepedia would be a lifetime's work. There are mistakes and errata on **literally every page**.